# Unpack dict from list where key is not None

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

Trying to unpack the `dict`s which are not `None` from a `list`:

```
In [4]: unpack_dict = [{'key': 'a'}, {'key_2': 'b'}, None]
```

Tried a dict comprehension

```
In [5]: {key: value for (key, value) in unpack_dict if (key, value) is not None}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-ec0e44b95586> in <module>()
----> 1 {key: value for (key, value) in unpack_dict if (key, value) is not None}

<ipython-input-5-ec0e44b95586> in <dictcomp>(.0)
----> 1 {key: value for (key, value) in unpack_dict if (key, value) is not None}

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

And a list comprehension:

```
In [6]: {**[x for x in [unpack_dict] if x is not None]}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ac36898d39a1> in <module>()
----> 1 {**[x for x in [unpack_dict] if x is not None]}

TypeError: 'list' object is not a mapping
```

Expected result:

```
{'key': 'a', 'key_2': 'b'}
```

What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to unpack either a dictionary or `None` to two variables (`key` and `value`). You can't unpack *either type* in this way. `None` is not iterable, and iteration over a dict would yield *only the keys*, not the values.

Loop over the dictionary items if there is a dictionary, otherwise loop over an empty sequence, and unpack the *iteration results*:

```
{key: value for d in unpack_dict for key, value in (d.items() if d else ())}
```

The `d.items() if d else ()` expression produces either an iterable of `(key, value)` pairs from a (non-empty) dictionary, or an empty tuple (causing that nested iteration to stop immediately).

Demo:

```
>>> unpack_dict = [{'key': 'a'}, {'key_2': 'b'}, None]
>>> {key: value for d in unpack_dict for key, value in (d.items() if d else ())}
{'key': 'a', 'key_2': 'b'}
```

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, you can do this with a `for` loop and successive calls to `dict.update`, which I think is quite readable:

```
>>> dct = {}
>>> for d in unpack_dict:
...    if d:
...       dct.update(d)
... 
>>> dct
{'key': 'a', 'key_2': 'b'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the built-in function [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

Assuming you actually do have a list of dicts or None, as per your example:

```
merged_dict = {}
for dict in filter(None, unpack_dict):
    merged_dict.update(dict)
```

Or in one line:

```
dict(pair for dict in filter(None, unpack_dict) for pair in dict.items())
```

Or if your input was supposed to be a list of *tuples*, then it's quite easy, and similar to what you were attempting:

```
unpack_dict = [('key': 'a'), ('key_2': 'b'), None]
{key: value for (key, value) in filter(None, unpack_dict)}
```